# AWS Glue Job fails at create_dynamic_frame_from_options when reading from s3 bucket with lot of files

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet, aws-glue

The data inside my s3 bucket looks like this...
s3://bucketName/prefix/userId/XYZ.gz

There are around 20 million users, and within each user's subfolder, there will be 1 - 10 files.

My glue job starts like this...

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("s3", {'paths': ["s3://bucketname/prefix/"], 'useS3ListImplementation':True, 'recurse':True, 'groupFiles': 'inPartition', 'groupSize': 100 * 1024 * 1024}, format="json", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

There are a bunch of optimizations like groupFiles, groupSize & useS3ListImplementations I have attempted, as shown above.

I'm using G.2X worker instances to provide the maximum memory for the jobs.

This job however fails consistently on that first line, with 'SDKClientException, Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0', and with ' Unable to execute HTTP request: Received close_notify during handshake' error on enabling useS3ListImplementations.

From the monitoring, I observe that this job is using only one executor, though I have allocated 10 (or 20 in some runs), and driver memory is growing to 100%, and CPU hovers around 50%.

I understand my s3 folders are not organized the best way. Given this structure, is there a way to make this glue job work?

My objective is to transform the json data inside those historical folders to parquet in one go. Any better way of achieving this is also welcome.